# Delete Java tag from 100% Android related questions

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Is it okay to delete Java tag from questions that are completely related to Android framework?

For example I recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24021916/1841194) thet are 100% related to Android framework not to Java.

Comment: In my opinion, no. The java tag still pertains to the language of the code in that question, and helps searchability.

Comment: That looks like Java code to me.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII You're right but the question owner did not ask any question about Java, he asked all about Android framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the code is written in Java, then why remove the tag?

There's plenty of Django + Python pairs floating about and it just makes sense. One day, perhaps, there might even be an Android framework written in a completely different language, targeted at a completely different environment.

But until then, if it fits, it fits.

Comment: Wow, this edit removed the Xamarian .NET Android reference. If you're going to edit my answers, please don't change the content of them.

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* include a language tag with your question.  Many users bookmark Java to answer Java questions of all sorts, including the Android ones.

Comment: If so, do I allowed to add Java tag to Android related questions?

Comment: You mean existing questions?  Why would you do that?  *There doesn't have to be a one-to-one correspondence between the Android and the Java tags.*  That said, if the question contains Java code, feel free to add the Java tag.

Comment: Yes, you are right sir, there isn't 1-1 correspondence. Many thanks