# Make android-java tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I was searching [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tagged questions, and noticed that around 20 percent of them are also tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). When I look at these questions, they look like a completely different language. I am proposing a new tag, the android-java tag. Even though they might be Java, they still use different syntax in some things, such as using `==` to compare strings, rather than the traditional Java way, the `equals()` method.

These may seem like very small differences, but ultimately they are the difference between a great answer and an incorrect, bad one. These do nothing except confuse the person who asked the question and the future readers of the question. This causes answers to be harder to find, and less convenient for the whole community.

I looked at two other posts([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254642/deleting-java-tag-from-questions-tagged-androidjava) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258235/delete-java-tag-from-100-android-related-questions)) which were good thoughts, but were more like complaints, without any solution. Why complain about a problem, when you could be fixing it?

Furthermore, the android-java tag would cause,

1. fewer duplicates
2. more convenience (for Android users *and* Java users)
3. fewer confusing answers, and
4. more correct ones.

---

Such a small tag could make a big impact (and a good one) on the Stack Overflow community, so please support the `android-java` tag.

Comment: You can search for [java] -[android] to get Java questions that aren't about Android.

Comment: but there are still confusing questions, and a beginner may not realize key differences between the android syntax and the standard java syntax

Comment: for example look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673152/not-getting-pop-up-dialog-in-proper-way)!!!!! seems like gibberish to me!

Comment: this wouldn't happen with `android-java` tag

Comment: It also doesn't happen as long as users test their answers before posting them. A Java programmer that never uses Android probably doesn't have an environment set up to even test an answer in. I also wouldn't expect any user who encounters a question they don't understand to attempt to answer it anyway. They'd just skip it.

Comment: when I was new to the community, i got confused with the android related posts, and I'm sure that I'm not the only one. I have nothing against android, but I think it is confusing, and would be better off not posted with the java tag. It is a different platform with different syntax.

Comment: So just add `android` to the **ignored tags**, just because you as a java developer can't understand it, doesn't mean a new tag is the solution

Comment: Android's syntax is no different than regular Java syntax. It's just another set of unfamiliar classes, like Swing or Spring or any other framework you haven't used.

Comment: @theProgrammer101: "*Even though they might be java, they still use different syntax in some things, such as using == to compare strings, rather than the traditional java way, the `equals()` method.*" Traditional or not, if it's legal Java syntax, then it's *legal Java syntax* and therefore has the same rights to the Java tag as any other question about Java.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because different platforms do not need a whole different tag. Java is Java, no matter what platform it is using. Making an android-java tag would mean there would have to be eclipse-java, netbeans-java, or other tags which seems unreasonable.

Comment: Thank you all for your time, but I realize this question is useless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Different frameworks for different languages can make questions seem foreign to people who are not familiar with that framework. But it's ultimately no different from seeing a question that uses Java and some other library; you see function calls you don't understand, file formats you don't know about, etc.

So the basis for drawing a line with the Android framework is weak. We could go on and on and on with this: C++ with Qt. C++ with MFC. OpenGL with Qt.

We don't create tags for *combinations* of languages and frameworks. If a question uses the Java language, then [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is a legitimate tag for that question. And however much you may see the Android additions as alien, the actual source code is still using the Java language.

If you're not interested in answering questions with the Android tag, we have ways to do that. You can add the tag to your ignore list, accessible in your user settings page. When you do so, questions using that tag won't show up on the main page, and even when looking at the list of questions for a tag, questions that use ignored tags will be dimmed.