# Burninate [kotlin-android]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [kotlin-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-android) tag has 32 questions and most of them are also tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) or both. Since [kotlin-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-android) refers to Kotlin when used with Android, it's essentially meaningless creating a specific tag for that. Related to a kotlin-android tag is also an [android-java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348515/make-android-java-tag) tag, but nothing ever came out of it. That particular tag was meaningless, and so is the kotlin-android tag.

And as mentioned in the `android-java` tag creation discussion:

> We don't create tags for combinations of languages and frameworks. If a question uses the Java language, then [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is a legitimate tag for that question

So I suggest burninating the tag and re-tagging the posts with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin).

Comment: I officially +1 one this effort for sure! Especially since I cleaned up most of them already. :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson problem solved then :)

Comment: not really, some moderator or someone still needs to delete and ban the tag otherwise it will get added to questions again, probably has already

Comment: @JarrodRoberson No new questions, and the tag wiki is gone. I think empty tags are deleted by the system. As for tag re-creation it'll only happen when specifically created by a new user with that access, so if that happens, asking for a ban then is a good approach

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The tag has now been auto-deleted. Apparently the timer to clean up all empty tags just passed. Blacklisting (making sure it can't get recreated) is a different thing, tags that got recreated multiple times qualify for that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since there's [precedence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348515/make-android-java-tag) to disallow such a tag, and the tag contains less than 50 questions, we could quickly handle the burninate, as described in [the burninate process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7296893):

> If you have **authoritative** knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have **conferred** with at least one other [trusted community member](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), *and* are dealing with a tag that has a **small number** of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little *ad hoc* help.

As it's already asked on meta, I'd leave it to gather votes for a day or two, and if there's no clear disagreement (e.g. over 70% of all votes are upvotes and no-one has voiced their disagreement), burninate it yourself (and possibly mention me in a comment for a little help).

Comment: Could you add a link to this "precedence"? Especially in the light of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba

Comment: Good point. I mean the link OP provided, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348515/make-android-java-tag). VBA is a different case in my opinion. VBA is visual basic for _applications_, a dialect of VB highly integrated with the application it's running in, and a different case in my opinion (even the IDE is integrated in the application). But even that has been subject to many debates.

Comment: You need to get buy-in from at least one user with >20k rep (i.e. a "[trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)"). As of yet, no one who has participated here qualifies.

Comment: Ah, missed that, if such a user comes along, please share your view. Else I hope one is present in socvr and willing to support this plan

Comment: I officially +1 one this effort for sure! Especially since I cleaned up most of them already. :-)

Comment: so who needs to delete the tag and ban it now?

Comment: Well, in a few hours, I'll do it. It just involves retagging all questions that have the tag, removing the tag and replacing it with [kotlin] and [Android]. It won't get banned (blacklisted) though, just removed as soon as it has no questions for a day

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth the tag has been cleaned up already (by Jarrod). The tag is not used by anything now

Comment: Ah, burninated it is then. We just need to wait a day for the system to remove it (and check that no-one sneaks in a question in the mean time). You can modflag your post, and ask a mod to mark it [meta-tag:status-completed].  Many thanks Jarrod!