# Merge [dagger-android] and [dagger.android] into [dagger]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

[dagger-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger-android) and [dagger.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger.android) both refer to [the dependency injection library](https://github.com/google/dagger) in the context of Android. That alone covers the merger of those two. However, taking it one step further, applying the [precedence from the `android-java` discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348515/6296561):

> We don't create tags for combinations of languages and frameworks. If a question uses the Java language, then [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is a legitimate tag for that question

I suggest that both [dagger-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger-android) and [dagger.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger.android) are made synonyms of [dagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dagger).

Comment: Btw, Dagger Android refers to the specific part of Dagger library (see https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html, https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/android/package-summary.html), not to general usage of Dagger on Android, like you've mentioned. Anyway, I think this synonym does make sense.

Comment: @VadimKotov both of those URLs 404 on me

Comment: hmm, that's strange. Just checked, it opens successfully

Comment: Both of Vadim’s links work for me. I’ve always wanted to stab a [dagger] into [android]. Bring forth your tags with useless prefixes and they shall be cut off!

Comment: @CodyGray they started working when I got on a different Wi-Fi. Probably a caching issue

Comment: Is this a [dagger] I see before me, it's tag wiki on my screen? Come, let me burninate thee.