# Rename [android-gradle] to [android-gradle-plugin]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Again using the precedence established in the proposed creation of [android-java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348544/6296561):

> We don't create tags for *combinations* of languages and frameworks. If a question uses the Java language, then [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is a legitimate tag for that question.

However, several of the questions on the tag (I don't have a figure on how many) refer to the Android Gradle plugin (which, for those of you who aren't familiar with Android, [is an actual plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)).

And as mentioned by [kkarakk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385405/rename-android-gradle-to-android-gradle-plugin?noredirect=1#comment699654_385405) (which I forgot to add when I wrote this), Gradle is a build system, and is used for both Android and Java, as well as with other JVM languages, Kotlin Native, and likely others as well. There's no difference between Gradle with desktop Java and Gradle with Android.

The tag wiki also expresses that it refers to the plugin:

> The Android Gradle Plugin is Android's standard build system.

I suggest renaming [android-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gradle) to [android-gradle-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gradle-plugin), to make it clear in the name as well that the tag doesn't refer to Gradle in combination with Android, but rather the Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: Makes sense since Gradle is also a standalone build tool that can be used outside of the android studio plugin functionality, with android even!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after going ahead with this a couple of weeks back... It turns out there's a hitch: this tag is currently sponsored, which means the sponsorship needs to be transferred to the new tag. No problem, right? Except... Apparently we're something like 40,000 tags over our limit in Google Ad Manager already, which means we can't add new tags until we get that figured out.

Since Google already payed for the sponsorship, it's not really kosher to take that away... So I've reverted the rename until we can figure out how to clear the logjam in Google's ad system. The Google giveth and the Google taketh away.

Sorry for the confusion; currently hoping to have this resolved within the next month.

Comment: Hmm. Google tools have a problem you want fixed. If you rename the tag, Google has a problem they want you to fix. This doesn’t seem like an unsolvable dilemma. Reverting the rename won’t help move things along.

Comment: Heh... This strategy... May have been discussed. But realistically, it's gonna be fixed, just not for a few weeks - so this is more a good-faith gesture than anything.