# Merge [android-proguard] into [proguard]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Proguard is a code obfuscation and minimization tool used with Android and Java. The [official website](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard) shows no difference between the tool when used in combination with Android, compared to when it's used in combination with Java, in terms of developer use or backend-wise.

The [android-proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-proguard) tag wiki also links to docs on shrinking. It has later (after the introduction of a second obfuscation tool), been redirected to a different site, that still links to Guardsquare's website in a couple places when Proguard is referenced. However, the internet archive stored a version [from 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216110650/http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) where the first line contains a link to Proguard's sourceforge page.

The point being, there is no separate version of Proguard for Android, meaning [android-proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-proguard) refers to Proguard in combination with Android.

From the proposed creation of [android-java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348544/6296561):

> We don't create tags for *combinations* of languages and frameworks. If a question uses the Java language, then [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is a legitimate tag for that question.

Can [android-proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-proguard) be merged into [proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proguard)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a proposal to add [android-proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-proguard) as a synonym for [proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proguard), proposed by Rolf ツ back on Jan 4 '17, but it was never voted upon or approved.

I approved the synonym, [android-proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-proguard) is now a synonym for [proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proguard), that is  [proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proguard) (× 3579) ← [android-proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-proguard) (× 1101).

I will wait a few days to see if there is any issue with this synonym, and then merge the tags (as tag merges are permanent, but synonyms aren't).