# Overusing the Java tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen several edits come through in the last week or so where the `java` tag was added to a question that happened to be using the Java language to implement their solution.  Is this an appropriate tag, especially when the question has more to do specifically with another framework or an API that's not specific to Java itself?

Comment: I don't see why not. If it's a language agnostic solution, then it probably doesn't need it but implementation in `java` seems relevant to have the `java` tag. What if the problem is related to somebody misusing or misunderstanding how a core Java feature works? What if there is a good alternative in already present in Java - e.g., a person is trying to implement a List and that's *not* part of their solution, whereas they can simply use `ArrayList` or something?

Comment: Could you provide some instances where that's happened so that we could see what you're seeing in context?

Comment: @VLAZ that's what I'm wondering about.  I think if someone is misusing a Java construct, then the `java` tag makes a lot of sense, but if they're just trying to read from a URL and messed up the query string, I'm less convinced, even if they happen to be doing it in the Java language.

Comment: @David but what if there is a problem you didn't see or recognise as core Java, yet somebody else who frequents the `java` tag does?

Comment: Perhaps someone is craving after the `java` tag badge ;)

Comment: [Yes, it's fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348544/6296561)

Comment: @Zoe's link hit on the idea that a reader may get generally bogged down or lost in the syntax of a language they're not familiar with.  Even if the "same issue" appears in multiple languages, it's not necessarily a problem because it improves readability and usability for many readers.

Comment: If you see that question has nothing to do with java then simply remove the tag from a question

Comment: You can't stop people from adding a java tag to a question which has a hint of java code - in that respect I wouldn't go out of my way to remove them. But I don't go out of my way to add such a tag either, it all depends on what tags are already present and how much they imply Java. For example if something is already tagged with JavaEE or Spring, I do not add a Java tag.