# When does a framework wrapper deserve its own tag?

Tags: discussion

I frequent the [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) tag. Its a popular charting framework for Javascript. It has grown to have a lot of wrappers, for example: [Android](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android), [iOS](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios), [React](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react), [Vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue), [Angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular), [Meteor](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-meteor) and others unofficially.

What I'm asking, in general, is this: When does a wrapper require a separate tag? I ask this because I see [react-highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-highcharts) pop up recently and thinking it might lead to other wrapper tags. Maybe this might as well be [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) + [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react)?

Any hard-hitting opinions on the matter? I have a feeling its a bit of "it depends", based on popularity, size/complexity and some other factors.

Comment: IMO, if experts on `framework` can generally answer questions about `wrapper + framework`, you could use both tags individually. If, on the other hand, experts on `framework` that are not familiar with `wrapper` wouldn't generally be able to help with these questions, a new tag combining both technologies would be more appropriate.

Comment: I've only small familiarity with Highcharts and even less with React (other than general principles). When I looked at the `react-highcharts` tag, the first question there was "Highcharts Graph not scaling to fill the full height of container in React". I'm not sure I can answer this with knowledge (assuming I was actually competent) of Highcharts alone nor with React alone. Well, *maybe* the latter but I'm not sure. So, to me, it seems that `react-highcharts` might have value. But not for all - the second question I saw was "DateTime whout seconds React highcharts" which should be generic.

Comment: It doesn't unless it's a completely separate library (for an instance if react-highcharts wasn't the same as highcharts, but instead a dataframe processing library for example). [Kill it with fire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348544/6296561)

Comment: Well, it's library-ish. It's a wrapper, as the OP says. [It takes the Highcharts library and creates a React component to house the chart](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts). Of course, Highcharts has [an official wrapper for that as well](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react)....

Comment: If react-highcharts is it's own unique thing then I am in favour of it having it's own tag - so questions about it do **not** need to be tagged react or highcharts. I say so while pretending to be an expert on react so I have added that tag to my watch list, making it easier for me to find questions to answer about it. If people would be forced to tag questions about react-highcharts with the react tag, I would be getting those questions in my personal homepage. I don't want them so I have to start adding exclusions and that list is already long enough as it is. But that's just me.

Answer (score -1):

The best bet is to use [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts) and [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) separately. This better coincides with the workflow most folks follow when creating filters and custom favorites looking for things to *answer*, so it's ideal if folks asking use the same nomenclature.

That said, if the combination of terms is the colloquial way folks would refer to a specific usage (as in while participating in spoken conversation), it could be worth explicitly disallowing the hyphenated combination with guidance to apply the tags separately.

I'm not by any means an expert on how it's being referenced in normal conversation (I'd leave it up to the mods ultimately), but that's the guidance we've been using with other libraries where many wrappers tend to exist to use them in different frameworks.

Think of any PHP PDF library. Then think of any PHP framework. There's a good chance every framework will have a wrapper for any given PDF library, yet we'd ask folks to apply the tags separately (as an example of something that once got kind of out of hand).