# Split [java-se] from [java]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

> [Are we removing the Java tag from questions not explicitly about "Java SE"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275290/are-we-removing-the-java-tag-from-questions-not-explicitly-about-java-se)

and

> [Deleting java tag from questions tagged android+java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254642/deleting-java-tag-from-questions-tagged-androidjava)

and

> [Delete Java tag from 100% Android related questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258235/delete-java-tag-from-100-android-related-questions)

are all examples where there has been confusion with the java-tag regarding examples which were not about Java-SE.

The tag-info of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) reads:

> Use this tag for questions referring to the Java programming language or Java platform tools.

So the tagging [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is correct on the questions mentioned in above posts. However there is also the tag-synonym [java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se) which after my understanding is a closer specification like android is which is not solely about the programming language in general. Further [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) exists as a single tag on its own.

Hence I would suggest splitting of [java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se) (or [javase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javase)) as tag from java and remove the synonym from it because technically they are different things. For example tagging a question [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is different from [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se) and searching for [java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se) would not bring up the android questions which are (correctly) tagged java anymore.

Comment: If we only split them up, I expect that a lot of java-se questions will still be posted under the java tag. Cleaning and separating them will probably take a lot of effort and likely isn't feasible ([tag:java] is one of the larger tags). Retagging new questions is possible with some effort, but is it worth it? Why exactly should we do this?

Comment: Because it would prevent things like the android+java things to happen and it would make it a lot easier to search for plain JavaSE questions to answer without having to deal with the noise of android questions. Although it is true that executing this idea is a lot of effort I think it would help searching what you want to find a lot. Maybe one could add a tag warning to the Java tag that a specification like android, JavaSE or JavaEE should be added similar to SQL with the different subsets like MySQL or sql-server.

Comment: Well, if the problem is the android questions, a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android) or [some configuration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251962/can-i-hide-questions-based-on-tag-names-from-my-feed) can hide them from you. That's not a strong point in my opinion.

Comment: It would still be a pain to get tagging right by adding another tag. It is much easier to search and exclude a tag `[java] -[android]`  if that's the only purpose (that = search for Java questions without seeing Android questions)

Comment: Ah! I have not been aware of that search exclusion. Maybe one should then at least add a note to the tag info? Because no matter how you tilt and turn it, Java as described in the tag wiki is not JavaSE nor vice versa.

Comment: You can, of course, suggest an edit to the tag information, acknowledging that the java tag is ok for android versions and with info on how to hide them. That's useful in my opinion. I'm not sure how many people look at it, though.

Comment: Then I will go ahead and do that in a minute. Thanks for your thoughts and help!

Comment: Welp by reading through the wiki it looks like it is completely written for JavaSE. I guess I will leave everything as it is including this question ^^

Comment: @geisterfurz007 not entirely, there is a mention of android studio at some point. But it is true, the wiki is still very much oriented towards the times before Android existed. It can use some love to at least reference the fact that involved SDK tooling is platform-specific.